# track request's on page load

Tags: php, javascript, html, http-headers

i analyzed a page that i'm working on with live http headers addon for FF and im seeing that is making request to the same page 2-3 time during the load of it. i checked for empty img tags that could be the reason but there is none on the html code. is there any addon out there or something that could let me track what resource is firing this request? or any other recommendation of what is should look apart from  the empty img tags.

the page have several javascript libraries and mootools with ajax calls, but none of them is causing it as they load the resources and the ajax calls are get request passing several parameters to the page, this unexpected request are clean one, whiteout parameters.

Regards,
Shadow.

**SOLUTION**

monitoring from the server side the request and commenting code, i realized that was making 3 request's

1) from a popup blocker checker that open an about:blank in theory but it was requesting the same page
2) a class used to check if flash was enabled
3) the yslow plugin for FF was making the last one.

i'm worried about this last one as it screw up a feature in my app, so i will need to have some alternative thing here :)

Comment: Have you tried using Firebug for FF?

Comment: i have it, how it can help with my problem? it can track the resources load at runtime and the request's made?

Comment: Yes, it can. Use the "net" tab to see all the requests made during the page load and XHR requests after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have access to server logs, you can find the answers there.
finally, you can use some sniffer software to see all http request sending by browser

Comment: yes, i have access to the server and i can see the request, the thing is, i need to know what in the browser/html is firing the request and is not something i could do from the server part.

Comment: what kind of documents does it request?

Comment: the same php page that the user is seeing, is like a php_self to give you an idea. for that reason the first thing i checked was in a empty <img> that usually loads the page itself inside

Comment: it may be some phantom records in server log. i also faced the same situation. i used sniffer tool and did not saw any additional requests sent from browser. so i still have no explanation for that phenomena